# azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter error on import

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-keyvault

When including compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.3.2'

as soon as I build my project and start application it throws this java runtime error

As far as I was able to find out was it runs fine when i import this in a new application but conflicts when I am using it in an application where i am already using 'azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter'

Comment: Could you please provide the error message in detail?

Comment: The problem that I have found is that it is conflicting azure-keyvault-spring -starter. Not sure why though. I have included these both in gradle and starts conflicting

    compile "com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter:2.3.2"
and      compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.3.2'

Comment: editing question to be more precise

Comment: As far as I knew, when we use spring boot azure key vault starter, we need to configure some settings in `application.properties`. Because when the application is starting, it will read these settings otherwise the application cannot start and throw error. Could you please check it? For more details, please refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-starter-keyvault-secrets and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the problem of netty version?

I think it a known problem: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/886